# Getting the available free space on a directory in linux

Tags: c, linux

Using a C program how to get the free size available in a directory ?

What are the library functions that i can use to achieve this.

Comment: Details please. Is there a quota?

Comment: Also, program or library?

Comment: I want to do this using program.

Answer (score 3):

A given *directory* does not have *free space*, it is the [*file system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (containing that directory) which has free space.

You can query that using the [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) command (you might [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) `"/bin/df ."`, but I don't recommend doing that) and the [statfs(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html) (and some other) syscall(s).

See [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Perhaps the limit is quota related, see [repquota(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/repquota.8.html), or resource-limit related, see `ulimit` builtin of bash and [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html). Maybe use `/proc/` pseudo-files, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

BTW, that limit is in fact only indicative: other programs and processes are also able to fill the directory (e.g. between the moment your program is querying it and the moment it is writing data).

Comment: technically correct, but his concept might be along the lines of "my sys admin limited the amount of space I can use in my home directory"

Comment: @true. Yes, disk quotas make things complicated.